# Bit or Bitten - which is correct usage?

Tags: usage, past-tense

"Spiderman was bit by a radioactive spider" versus "Spiderman was bitten by a radioactive spider" - which one is correct usage ?

Not sure if "bitten" is formally recognized as English or just a colloquial extension.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: Verb - simple past: 'bit', past participle: 'bitten'. However, that didn't help me with the question.

Comment: Thank you @Mari-LouA, for the constructive suggestion. I wasn't aware of ELL. In the meantime, and after reading around a bit more, especially at a site pointed to by another ESE member on another question I asked, I think I have the answer. 

 While I am not still one hundred percent sure, but I think the first sentence is correct, but the second one would have been correct if it said "Spiderman had been bitten by a radioactive spider".

Comment: Your analysis is correct, well done! :)

Comment: Hmm. But *simple past* is *bit*: "A radioactive spider bit Spiderman." *Was <verbed>* requires the past participle, so actually both *was* and *had been* require *bitten*. I'll send this over to ELL as they'll be able to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 7):

It's the opposite. "Bitten" is standard. "Bit" is a more-or-less common non-standard form.

As Andrew Leach's comment explains,

> Simple past is bit: "A radioactive spider *bit* Spiderman." *Was*  requires the past participle, so actually both was and had been require bitten.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted.  *Bit* as a past participle is, I think, generally considered nonstandard, but it's surprisingly common (see e.g. [GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=32844033)) so it's worth describing to learners.

Comment: @snailplane, I can see someone thinking this answer is a bit terse. I thought the other answer explained a lot about *why* the answer is what it is, but never actually explicitly answered the question, so I was trying to fix that.

Comment: I did not downvote the answer (I always leave a comment when I do)- to be make the point. But I find saying the other answer does not "explicitly answer the question" is a bit "over the top". If a form is in a dictionary doesn't it mean it is recognized as English and "sometimes" and "also" are clear aren't they? We are encouraged to give sources and examples on ELL.

Comment: @snailplane sorry you're right. deleted.

Comment: The only thing I could have said but did not say for ELL is that some (not all) EFL teachers will cross past participle "bit" out as a mistake: it is not in most irregular verbs lists. And that would be very useful to ELL students. But I'm not sure we are encouraged to do so. –  Laure 5 mins ago

Comment: @Laure, you give lots of useful information about the p.p. of *bite*, but you never explicitly say that the p.p. is needed in op' s example.

Comment: @ThePhoton: OP's question is clear: do we say "was bit" or  "was bitten" ..."**Not sure if "bitten" is formally recognized as English**".  It is clear they knew past participle is needed, and that was not their question. But since lots of dictionaries only give "bitten" they could not understand why "bit" is sometimes encountered, which I think I have answered with as much info as I could find - except the ngram. And OP did not seem to say I answered another question.

Answer (score 5):

Among the grammar books and dictionaries I have just consulted only  *A grammar of Contemporary English* (Quirk & al) and Longman's *Dictionary of the English Language* mention past participle of *bite* to be "sometimes" (Quirk) "also" (Longman) *bit*. *OED* (1994 CDrom edition) says "also bit".

The [*free dictionary* has](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bite) both forms.
 *Cambridge* on line  gives both forms for past participle for [US English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/bite) and only "bitten" for [UK English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/bite).

Most online lists of irregular verbs I've consulted do not mention the *bit* form for the past participle.

The question appears on forums:

Quoting @AndrewLeach on our sister site [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/154804/12918) :

> *Bit* is not a past participle of *bite* in Standard English; it's dialectal. The answer implies that both have equal validity and application.

*Grammarist.com* has a   [Bit vs. bitten entry](http://grammarist.com/usage/bit-bitten/)

> Still, even though bitten is conventional in such uses, bit is sometimes used as the past participle [...]  But such instances are rare. In edited writing, bit is usually the past tense...

A long discussion - apparently among English natives on the subject [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/AboutTheUsageOfBite/bvkqch/post.htm).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sources and the last link to the extended discussion.

Comment: [Here is an ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+bit%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+has+bit%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+has+bitten%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+has+bitten%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20bit%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20bit%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20bitten%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20bitten%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) comparing the two wrt BrE and AmE.

Comment: @Drew thanks for ngram. Interesting to see there's hardly ant difference between us and gb English.